# Google map zoom into direction points

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map where I'm showing directions between two points and I'm trying to `fit to bounds` the map.
The two points show up correctly on the map but I can't get it to `fit to bounds`

This is the setup I have:

```
#map
  width: 100%
  height: 400px

<div id="map"></div>
```

and this is the javascript for the two points:

```
var handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){

    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var METERS_TO_MILES = 0.000621371192;

    directionsDisplay.setMap(handler.getMap());
    var request = {
        origin:      new google.maps.LatLng(<%=@origin%>),
        destination: new google.maps.LatLng(<%=@destination%>),
        travelMode:  google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING,

    };


    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            var totaldistance = 0;
            var route = response.routes[0];
            // display total distance information.
            for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
                totaldistance = totaldistance + route.legs[i].distance.value;
            }
            document.getElementById('distance').innerHTML += "<strong>Total walking distance is " + ((totaldistance * METERS_TO_MILES * 10) / 10).toFixed(2) + " miles</strong>";
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    });

});
```

This is what I tied thus far but didn't work:

```
handler.fitMapToBounds();
handler.getMap().setZoom(15);
```

Also tried this:

```
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        preserveViewport: true
    });
```

Any ideas how I can implement this?

**Update 1**

I failed to mention previously that I have the map inside a dynamic tab:

```
$(function() {

    //show new panel function
    function ShowNewPanel(theLink, theTab, thePane) {
        //activate new pane
        theTab.find('.tab-pane-show.active').fadeOut(200, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            $(thePane).fadeIn(200, function() {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });
        });

        //activate new link
        theTab.find('.tab-nav-show li').removeClass('active');
        theTab.find('.tab-nav-show a[href="'+thePane+'"]').parent('li').addClass('active');
    }

    //Using Tab Links
    $('.tab .tab-nav-show ul li a, a.tab-anchor').on('click', function() {
        var $theLink = $(this);
        var $theTab = $theLink.closest('.tab');
        var $thePane = $theLink.attr('href');
        ShowNewPanel($theLink, $theTab, $thePane)
    });


});




<div class="tab">
  <nav class="tab-nav-show">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#details">Details</a></li>
      <li><a href="#map-location">Location</a></li>
      <li><a href="#comments">Comments</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

  <div class="tab-pane-show" id="map-location">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `LatLngBounds` object - adding whatever points you need to it and then calling the `fitBounds` method

```
var handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var METERS_TO_MILES = 0.000621371192;

    directionsDisplay.setMap(handler.getMap());
    var request = {
        origin:      new google.maps.LatLng(<%=@origin%>),
        destination: new google.maps.LatLng(<%=@destination%>),
        travelMode:  google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING,

    };
    bounds.extend( request.origin );
    bounds.extend( request.destination );

    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            var totaldistance = 0;
            var route = response.routes[0];
            // display total distance information.
            for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
                totaldistance = totaldistance + route.legs[i].distance.value;
            }
            document.getElementById('distance').innerHTML += "<strong>Total walking distance is " + ((totaldistance * METERS_TO_MILES * 10) / 10).toFixed(2) + " miles</strong>";
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            map.fitBounds( bounds );
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @RamRaider. I tried what you suggested but unfortunately it doesn't `fit to bounds`... I failed to mention that I have the map inside a dynamic tab, I updated my question with more info on that. Maybe it has to do something with that?

Comment: `TypeError: map.fitBounds is not a function. (In 'map.fitBounds( bounds )', 'map.fitBounds' is undefined)`

Comment: it needs a reference to the map object - whatever that happens to be called

Comment: I'm sorry and how do I do that?

Comment: If you mean this `handler.fitBounds( bounds );` but still id dint work

Comment: sorry - been out for lunch. Hard to know what the reference is called - the variable assigned to `new google.maps.Map( DIV,OPTIONS  )`

Comment: Thanks for the @RamRaider... just to give you a heads up,it works just fine if I place the map inside the active tab. Even without your additional code it works fine inside the active tab. I think that the problem has do something with that. I updated my question with more info regarding the tabs code. You can take a look if you want!